# How to fetch logo of the paylater provider services like ICICI pay later in Razorpay Custom UI Android SDK 3.9.20?

Tags: android, razorpay, razorpay-andoid-sdk

There are methods available to fetch logos for net-banking like `getBankLogoUrl` and wallets like `getWalletSqLogoUrl`, but there is no option available either in the Razorpay documentation or sample app on GitHub Repo to fetch logos of the pay-later provider services. If anyone knows the method, please help.

I had tried using above function for net-banking and wallets to try and fetch it for pay-later options, but it's clearly not working.